# Certificate with password

Tags: c++builder

I consume a web services client.

I have a certificate with password. I can retrieve the certificate from my store and i can use it in `InternetSetOption()`.

But I don't know how to send the password with the certificate.

Here is an example:

```
LPWSTR pswzFirstCert = L"xxxxx";// Subject of the first certificate.
LPWSTR pPassword = L"yyyyyy";// Spassword
HCERTSTORE hSystemStore; // The system store handle
PCCERT_CONTEXT pDesiredCert = NULL;

hSystemStore = CertOpenStore(CERT_STORE_PROV_SYSTEM, 0, NULL, CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_CURRENT_USER,L"MY");
if(hSystemStore == NULL)
{
    ShowMessage("Not Opened the MY system store.");
    return;
}

// Get a certificate that has the string "Full Test Cert" in its subject.
if(pDesiredCert)
    CertFreeCertificateContext(pDesiredCert);

pDesiredCert=CertFindCertificateInStore(hSystemStore, MY_ENCODING_TYPE, 0, CERT_FIND_SUBJECT_STR, pswzFirstCert, NULL);
if(pDesiredCert == NULL)
{
    ShowMessage("The certificate was not found.");
    return;
}

if(hSystemStore)
    CertCloseStore(hSystemStore, CERT_CLOSE_STORE_CHECK_FLAG);

if( InternetSetOption (Data, INTERNET_OPTION_CLIENT_CERT_CONTEXT, (LPVOID)pDesiredCert, sizeof (CERT_CONTEXT) ) == FALSE )
    ShowMessage("InternetSetOption failed with error.");

if( InternetSetOption (Data, INTERNET_OPTION_PASSWORD, (LPVOID)pPassword, sizeof (pPassword) ) == FALSE )
    ShowMessage("InternetSetOption failed with error.");

if(pDesiredCert)
    CertFreeCertificateContext(pDesiredCert);
```

Comment: You are leaking `hSystemStore` if `CertFindCertificateInStore()` retuns NULL. And `INTERNET_OPTION_PASSWORD` is for specifying an HTTP authentication password, not a certificate password. WinInet does not have an option to specify a certificate password.

Comment: Do you have an idea to do that?